# Excel - extract unique values from a column with several values in each cell

Tags: excel, list

I have a list of publishers in a column.
I need to extract unique publishers into a separate list, like so:

```
PLoS
Nature
IMA
NAoS
Elsevier
PLoS
T&F, Ebsco
ONCOTARGET
Oxford, ProQuest
Nature
Elsevier, ProQuest
ACS
Springer
Ebsco/ProQuest
PLoS
Elsevier
Nature
```

Needs to become:

```
PLoS
Nature
IMA
NAoS
Elsevier
T&F
Ebsco
ONCOTARGET
Oxford
ProQuest
ACS
Spring
```

As you can see, in lines where there were several publishers, I need to count them all uniquely.

Is this possible?

Comment: Copy the list, then use `Data/Remove duplicates` to keep only the unique ones

Comment: That will not at all reach the result I'm looking for. The only thing it will do is delete rows which have the same exact values. What I want is to take a  cell like this: T&F, Ebsco
and extract it to two different lines:
T&F
Ebsco

Comment: Or see https://excelxor.com/2014/09/30/list-of-unique-entries-from-column-of-space-separated-strings/ and make the necessary small amendments such that the set-up works for comma-separated, as opposed to space-separated, strings. Give me a shout if you have any difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This short macro both parses the data and removes duplicates:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim K As Long, i As Long, N As Long
    Dim ary, a

    K = 1
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ary = Range("A1:A" & N)

    For Each a In ary
        a = Replace(a, ", ", "/")
        If InStr(1, a, "/") > 0 Then
            bry = Split(a, "/")
                For Each b In bry
                    Cells(K, 2) = b
                    K = K + 1
                Next b
        Else
            Cells(K, 2).Value = a
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next a

    Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

[image]